# copying data structures and space complexity

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

I am often asked to write functions which take a certain type of parameter such as a String and manipulate it in some way that would be a lot easier if it were some other data structure. Can I convert a String to a character array and set the String to null while considering my function to take O(1) space or does copying all the elements make it O(N) even if I immediately delete the other copy? I use Strings as an example because they are immutable. In another case, I would try to delete data from one structure as i add it to the other.

I am just using String and char[] as examples here. In general, I want to know if copying my data reduces the space complexity of my algorithm even if I'm deleting the other copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying penalizes your space complexity because the original and the copy are both in memory at the same time (even if this is only briefly the case), so you need to have that extra memory available.  An in-memory algorithm is able to execute even if you don't have any more memory available.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that my function would only require O(1) space if I could delete from one structure as I built the other? Like if I could add to an arraylist while deleting from a stack?

Comment: @user137717 That's correct, assuming that you've got a constant-sized buffer for the arraylist (as opposed to a buffer that's some percentage of the current size)

Comment: @user137717 I need to amend that comment - when an arraylist is resized it usually needs to perform another copy (e.g. you've got an arraylist size `n`, you allocate a new arraylist size `n` + 10, copy the old array to the new array, and deallocate the old array), which would mean that the copy would require linear space.  In order for it to require constant space you would need to copy into something like a chunked list (linked list of arrays).  Note that a language like C might allow an in-place array resize using `realloc` (though this depends on the `realloc` implementation)